# How to escape semicolon?

Tags: bash, perl

I'm trying to run a command similar to this with bash and can't figure out how to escape the semicolon:

```
./script.pl data='!'"data;more_data"'!'
```

When my script reads the data, all it gets is "!data".

```
./script.pl data='!'"data\;more_data"'!'
```

The value I see is "!data\".

How should I be escaping the semicolon?

The Perl script uses CGI and param to get the data.

```
my $data = param("data");
print "$data\n";
```

Comment: What does the parsing part of `script.pl` look like? My script consisting of `print "$ARGV[0]\n";` isn't confused by the semicolon.

Comment: my $data = param("data");
print "$data\n";

Comment: Then what is `param()`?

Comment: Just to be clear: it's not a shell problem. `read var <<< data='!'"data\;more_data"'!'; echo "$var"` isn't confused either.

Comment: param is a utility function in CGI.  Testing with ARGV looks like it works... meaning something is going on in the perl library.  

http://perldoc.perl.org/CGI.html

Comment: @DemiImp Where did you mention CGI?

Comment: I mistook this as a bash problem, I thought the CGI library was "dumb" and was doing the bare minimum.  It looks like if you escape the semicolon via %3b, param reads the whole value.

Comment: @BenjaminW. If you post/repost an answer similar to mine, I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in Perl.  The CGI library's param() function will treat semicolons as delimiters, even when a script is called on the command line.

To get param() to work correctly, escape the semicolon as %3b.